# Расположить jFrame в правый нижний угол экрана

Tags: java, swing

Мне надо расположить `jFrame` в правый нижний угол экрана, как это сделать?
С учетом панели задач, и os.

Comment: Не могли бы вы показать минимальный компилируемый код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Windows 7 такой код работает:

```
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    Rectangle desktopBounds = ge.getMaximumWindowBounds();

    System.out.println( desktopBounds );

    JFrame frame = new JFrame( "test" );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    final int width = 320;
    final int height = 200;
    frame.setBounds( 
            desktopBounds.x + desktopBounds.width - width,
            desktopBounds.y + desktopBounds.height - height,
            width,
            height
        );

    frame.setVisible( true );
}
```

Comment: И на линуксе тоже ваш метод работает) Щяс еще пару тестов и если все получится к ответу +1